# mysql error: Too many connections for remote server

Tags: mysql

I am using 3 servers and one database server. I use private ip to connect to mysql server. But i get this kind of error many time.

I tried to turn off mysql.allow_persistent in php and raise max connections and connection error in mysql server but no effort.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Link-ID == false, connect failed

mysql error: Too many connections

I also saw a lot of TIME_WAIT connected over port 3306. How can i tune MySQL server properly.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use mysql_close() at the end of every page?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `max_connections` setting is not a limit for the total number of connections, but rather the number of connections that a single user can open.

To help fix this, be sure that:

- You're closing connections when finished, using mysql_close()
- You're not using persistent connections - bad idea!
- Try running `SET GLOBAL max_connections = ###` in SQL, replacing the #s with a desired amount.
- Look in and modify your my.cnf file to change the max # of connections - watch out for memory/load issues.

Comment: still got the problem. I am really confused